# Android NetowrkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, sockets, network-protocols, networkonmainthread, ar.drone

*Hi !!*

I try to build an Android Application to control the Ar drone.
But i have a problem when i try to connect my device with the drone.
I created a Thread to do a socket. But when i run it in the main activity i have a exception :  **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException** .

This is my code with my Thread in ThreadCmd class:

```
String commande="";
byte[] cmdToByte;
String iPinString;
InetAddress IpDrone;
DatagramSocket clientSocket;
Thread threadDecollage;
TextView tv ;
boolean etat;
DatagramPacket sendPacketWithCmd;
private byte[] ip = {(byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)1, (byte)1 };
boolean isRunning = true;
private final static long TIME_SLEEP= 20;


        public void run() {         


            try {
                IpDrone = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                etat = false;
            }


            try {
                clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                etat = false;
            }

            while(isRunning){
                runControl();
                try {
                     Thread.sleep(TIME_SLEEP);
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

        }
            public void runControl(){



    commande ="AT*REF=1,290717696<LF>AT*REF=2,290717952<LF>AT*REF=3,290717696<LF>";




          cmdToByte = commande.getBytes();


            try {

                sendPacketWithCmd = new DatagramPacket(cmdToByte,cmdToByte.length,IpDrone,5556);                    
                clientSocket.send(sendPacketWithCmd);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                etat = false;
            }
            etat = true;
            isRunning=false;
            }


            public boolean retourneetat(){
                return etat;
            }
```

After in the main activity :

```
 Threadcmd tc = new Threadcmd();
 tc.run();
```

I dont see my error so i ask to you if you can help me !! ( i don't forget the permission)

ps: please excuse my english :)

Comment: Can we see the actual class declaration please?

Comment: Please add your activity code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tc.run();
```

This is your problem. Here you call the run() method on the same thread.

In order to actually start a new thread, call
`tc.start();`

Comment: Thanks for your rapid answer !
I have already try with **tc.start()** but the treatment did not.
My command wasn't send to the drone, or maybe it's my socket who is wrong ?!
Have you got any idea ?

Comment: If the app does not crash, that probably means that the thread started properly.

If the commands aren't reaching the drone, try checking your logcat to see if there's any information there.

Comment: OK finally it has take off with success; Thanks a lot. The problem was well the tc.start().